# How to add .png file in login page

Tags: html, css

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
      <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\Online_Examination_System\images\User_Icon.png" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />  
      <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="uname" placeholder="login">
      <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="pass" placeholder="password">
      <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In" name="subt">
    </form>
```

I need some help for the above code as I want to display an image in my html form so if any one could suggest something please. The image is not shown instead its alternate text i.e "User Icon" always appear

Comment: Can you see some error on console? Are you sure the name and directory are correct?

Answer (score 2):

You are giving wrong image address in image src.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
  <img src="./images/User_Icon.png" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />  
  <input type="text" id="login" class="fadeIn second" name="uname" placeholder="login">
  <input type="password" id="password" class="fadeIn third" name="pass" placeholder="password">
  <input type="submit" class="fadeIn fourth" value="Log In" name="subt">
</form>
```

**Note:** your image must be in images folder.

Comment: can you accept this answer? if it is working for you?

Answer (score 0):

your file path is wrong and it shows your alternate text.

try it:

```
<img src="./images/User_Icon.png" id="icon" alt="User Icon" />
```

be sure that your User_Icon.png is in images folder!
good luck.

Answer (score -2):

You have to use '/' instead of '\'.
Your path should be : "./images/User_Icon.png"

Comment: Nope. It should be `./images/User_Icon.png` or similar

Comment: Thanks!! I appreciate for you taking effort